# Stereo songs are not being played stereo

Tags: ios, audio, music, accessibility, sound-volume

iPhone 13 Pro. 17.3
If I play "Love me two times" by the Doors, or Money by Pink Floyd or, say, Bohemian Rhapsody - all classic songs that play around with Left and Right channels in the mix, on my AirPods I get no stereo separation. If I use a Lightning to 3.5mm adapter with proper headphones - the same.

The same happens if I turn off dolby atmos.

What is iOS doing?

Answer (score 5):

Argh! I totally missed I had setup an Accessibility Setting

Accessibility > Audio & Visual

Check Mono Audio not on. Check Balance is in the middle.